# MongoDB projection is result of boolean of other fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, projection

I want a new field in a resultset to be a projection. In which the value is the logical AND of two other fields.

`foo` and `bar` are Boolean fields on the collection. I want the new projection `fooAndBar` to be the result of the logical `AND` of said fields.

```
$project : {
    'fooAndBar': {
         { $and: { [ {'$foo': 1 }, {'$bar' : 1} ] } }
     }
}
```

I cannot get this to work. I've tried using `$cond` too. Is this possible, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this, it'll work

```
{
"$project": {
  "fooBar": {
    $and: [
      "$foo",
      "$bar"
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/eDL-XH56QmY

Comment: Thanks! I would not have figured that out. That wasn't clear in the documentation that just listing the fields in `$and` would work - instead, all example I found indicated you had to include the `field: 1`.

How did you know this?

Comment: I am not an expert in mongoDB, but since mongo works like JS I had a guess that it'll work. Hopefully an expert would be able to answer it more better.